# Junit Ignores my @Transactional annotation in services

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

We have spring services in our project. for example UserService.

These services use the @Transactional annotation.

We just tried to execute junit tests that involves these services and for some reason the @Transactional annotations are ignored. (For example, i use a @Test without @Transactional , it goes to a service that is indeed anotated @Transactional, in that service it saves a new object(entity) the entity is being saved in the DB before the end of the transaction (Commit).)

I would like to point out that we don't want our junit tests to be annotated with @Transactional themselves.

Is it possible to enforce junit to not ignore the @Transactional annotations in our services?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you experience the fact that it isn't `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly tell JUnit to use transactions (example from reference):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"example/test-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=false)
public class CustomConfiguredTransactionalTests {
    // class body...
}
```

Then you can use @NonTransactional/@Rollback/etc annotations in order to control the behavior for particular methods.

Comment: This answer here at SO may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11492402/1990089.

Answer (score 0):

Manual configuration is required as previously mentioned, as transactions are not persisted in Spring test contexts.

Spring reference for this topic can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx)